# Kotlin annotate receiver of extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, kotlin-extension

I would like to restrict on which constant value extension function can be called. For example function like:

```
@IdRes
fun <T : View> Int.find() = findViewById<T>(this)
```

If this was called on real id, it's fine:

```
R.id.someView.find<TextView>() // ok
```

But this should make compilation error:

```
42.find<TextView>() // should be compile error
```

Is annotating extension receiver supported in Kotlin?

Answer (score 13):

As described in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), you can use the following syntax:

```
fun @receiver:IdRes <T : View> Int.find() = ...
```

However, note that the Kotlin compiler is not aware of the semantics of the Android annotations, so their incorrect use is never a compilation error; it's at best a failed lint check.

Comment: This doesn't highlight the call when `R.color.colorPrimary.find()` is used

Comment: Most likely the lint checks don't handle annotations on the receiver. You can file an issue in the Android issue tracker.